# A word for all groups in university of the same specialty graduating in the same year?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Basically what I wanna to say is that one of the students was the best among all others of his specialty in the year he graduated, not like the best graduate, but the best in his specialty.

Right now all I can think of if the word batch: "best of his batch". But is this the the right one, or there should be another one? Clean and simple way of saying it in a few words would be very much appropriated as well.

Comment: -1 It seems to me your question is not clear  and your title is different from your explanation. Please edit your question accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think you may use ***[course](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/course):***

noun (CLASSES)

> - a set of ​classes or a ​plan of ​study on a ​particular ​subject, usually ​leading to an ​exam or ​qualification:
>
>   - *Tim did a three-year course in ​linguistics at Newcastle.*

(Cambridge University)

Comment: Thank you very much, but unfortunately it doesn't seem so. You see, I want to say about a graduate who is the best not in the whole university nor in attending of some specific, but who has the best diploma in some particular field among all his classmates,

Comment: @RichardM So, you should edit your question because the title of your question says otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Consider,

***class***

> (*Education*) *chiefly US* a group of students who graduated in a specified year: *the class of '53*. [CED](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Class)

***graduating class***

> The body of students who graduate together this year. [WordNet by Farlex](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/graduating+class)

Comment: According to that OP's title is the correct answer. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The word you may be looking for is ***cohort***.

*Nathaniel achieved first place in the 2015 **cohort** of linguistics graduates.*

Answer (score 0):

So one of the students is a "specialty- master". First is the hyphening rule to compound when introduced to new terms, then after it will qualify or disqualify common usage, but you just have to see if it gets any recognition. The general public usually adopts much quicker when spoken to by politicians, philosophers, celebrities and alike.

However you don't have to approve with what is aforementioned, and can go with the "best of the/his/her field". The best always implies the best in something. So you would have to specify nonetheless in what the student is best of or in.